# Evaluation of Indefinite Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the integral $\int\frac{1}{t^{3/2}+t+1}dt$.

I took $\sqrt{t}=x$ which gave $2\int\frac{x}{x^{3}+x^2+1}dx$. How to proceed now? Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Try the method using rational fraction.

Comment: @Arbuja: of course it has. It is a quotient of polynomials and the roots of the denominator have a closed form. This decomposes in elementary fractions (linear and quadratic denominators) which integrate with $\log$ and $arctan$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Subhadeep Dey** gave the [right approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) in the comment section. However, this is a special 
 case of the [cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots), irreducible over the rationals, which makes matters a bit more [complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Hyperbolic_method_for_one_real_root). 
 It can be factored as $(x+r)\bigg[x^2+(1-r)~x+\dfrac1r~\bigg],~$ where $u=\cosh\bigg[\dfrac13\cdot\cosh^{-1}\bigg(\dfrac{29}2\bigg)\bigg]$ 
 and $r=\dfrac{1+2u}3.~$ Using these notations, things should run smoothly, and, in case you'd want 
 to verify your result, the final answer can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1lay.png).

Answer (score 1):

After the proposed substitution and factorization of the denominator, you get

$$\frac x{x^3+x^2+1}=\frac a{x+a}+\frac{ax+c}{x^2+bx+c},$$

where $-a$ is the real root.

The first term integrates with $\ln(|x+a|)$, and the second is further decomposed as

$$\frac a2\frac{2x+b}{x^2+bx+c}+\frac d{x^2+bx+c}.$$

The first term is immediate, and by shifting the variable by  $-\dfrac b2$ you reduce the last one to

$$\frac e{x^2+f}.$$

Depending on the sign of $f$, this integrates as an $\arctan$ or $\text{artanh}$.